# Laravel Elixir + Webpack: Custom output filename?

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-elixir

I'm using Laravel Elixir and trying to dump Webpack output to a custom-named file.  My Gulpfile has the following lines:

```
mix.webpack(
    './assets/js',
    'dist/assets/js/custom.js'
);
```

Surprisingly, this creates an extra folder in my `dist` folder:

```
dist/assets/js/custom.js/custom.js
```

Alternatively, I tried this just to see what happens:

```
mix.webpack(
    './assets/js',
    'dist/assets/js'
);
```

The result is like:

```
dist/assets/js/b40893aeee1432abcd.js
```

What is going wrong here?  I just want `dist/assets/js/custom.js`

Comment: You have the wrong "elixir" tag. I will retag the question.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is the path of your output file. It will be

```
mix.webpack('./assets/js','public/dist/assets/js/custom.js');
```

Comment: Right.  As I said, that's not working.  It's creating an extra subfolder.

Comment: Specify your source file